# Size of Chunk in Data.ByteString.Lazy

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, bytestring

Module `Data.ByteString.Lazy` contain own implementation of `ByteString` type:

```
data ByteString = Empty | Chunk !S.ByteString ByteString
```

And [there](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html) are following phrase about size of chunk:

> The default chunk size is 64k, which should be good in most
>   circumstances. For people with large L2 caches, you may want to
>   increase this to fit your cache.

But nothing about how to do it. How can I increase default chunk size? Also, whether I will get an increase of performance, if chuck size will be significantly greater than those L2 cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have to edit the source and install manually.

Chunk sizes are set [at the end of Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/src/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Internal.html#defaultChunkSize).